# ColdFusion CFMail wont send HTML

Tags: email, coldfusion

I have a weird problem and its got me stumped. If I send an email like this (below) it sends fine. The content of the email is html and sending using the first method shows the html content as text as expected.

```
<cfmail to="xxxx.xxxx@xxxx.com" from="xxxx.xxxx@xxxx.com" subject="To Oxint">
```

I change nothing in the email except change the cfmail line to this (below)

```
<cfmail to="xxxx.xxxx@oxint.com" from="xxxx.xxxx@xxxx.com" subject="To Oxint" type="html">
```

The email is not received. Not in my junk or spam folder. Just not received. CF mail logs show my email as successfully sent.

I've got our network team looking for issues as well, but its baffling. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried any other mail clients/addresses? Maybe yours is blocking the email for some reason?

Comment: tried millions (literally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some e-mail clients deny HTML mails without a plain part. Try this:

```
<cfmail from="someone@somewhere.com" to="someone@somewhereelse.com" subject="always deliver e-mails in plain as well">
    <cfmailpart type="text/plain">Here is some text.</cfmailpart>
    <cfmailpart type="text/html">Here is some <b>bold</b> text.</cfmailpart>
</cfmail>
```

Order matters here. First `text/plain`, then `text/html`.

Comment: Nope that didn't work either. Without the html bit, works fine. With the html bit - nothing

Comment: Can you check what the mail server is actually doing? I can't think of any other ColdFusion related issue.

Comment: Well on one hand the server logs show my email sent successful but then another log show's this `"Error","scheduler-2","09/16/15","18:27:24",,"Invalid Addresses"`

Comment: That does sound like a SMTP issue. Do you use a relay server?

Comment: This was actually the problem. without the plain text and html text elements both present this was enough for our mail servers to block it as spam, with those elements included and some other changes it first came though as spam but now comes through as genuine email. Thanks loads